# Google spam report, have they ever punished a bad site you reported?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, spam

You have reported a bad site on [Google Webmaster Tools SPAM report](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport).

Assuming you are sure it was a bad site, **did you see Google punishing it or doing something after your report?**

Thanks

Comment: Made this community wiki since there isn't a right answer

Comment: It's true, I did not thought about it.

Answer (score 3):

I did once, for a site which had lots of hidden links.

I received no acknowledgment, but within 7 days the offending site disappeared from the front page of results (I didn't check how far down they slipped, they may well have disappeared altogether) they re-appeared 6-7 weeks later, slightly further down the first page with the hidden links removed.

Comment: The system works! Though I personally prefer the personalized search Google used to offer, where you could choose to hide a website from all your future search results. It takes less time than filing a report, and if Google added a "mark as spam" button (since sometimes you might hide a site that is irrelevant to your search, but not spam) they could apply the same type of collaborative filtering that Gmail uses to filter out spam.